# How to use javascript variable out of the scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I am using `$.get` functionality to get json data from action method. But out of `$.get()` function JavaScript variable getting default value.

code look like:

```
var data = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = "/Controller/Action";
    $.get(url, null, function (Data) {
       data = JSON.stringify(Data);
       console.log(data);
    });
    console.log(data);
 });
```

Output display look like:

```
[{"Name":"Jatin","Address":"surat","colorScheme":"#1696d3"},{"Name":"Jatin","Address":"surat","colorScheme":"#1696d3"},{"Name":"Jatin","Address":"surat","colorScheme":"#1696d3"}]
```

And then

> **Display `0`.**

How may I use Data value out of scope?

Comment: First of all, why would data be anything but a string, and secondly, you can't return from an asynchronous call.

Comment: Because, i want this data in json out side of this $.get() function.

Comment: You can't, that's what asynchronous means.

Answer (score 3):

Don't declare 'var' in front of data in the $.get call. This declares a new variable. Since data is already defined outside the function scope, simple change the value by doing "data = JSON.stringify(Data);"

```
        var data = 0;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var url = "/Controller/Action";
            $.get(url, null, function (Data) {
               data = JSON.stringify(Data);
               console.log(data);
            });
            console.log(data);
         });
```

Edit: After chatting to OP, he was trying to use the response data from $.get in a synchronous manner. For that, I suggested either moving the code that relies on the response data in an ajax success function or use jquerys $.when() function

Comment: I am not getting your point can you give me updated code as per you said.

Comment: Look closely, my answer does contain updated code. Instead of "var data = JSON.stringify(Data)" it's just "data = JSON.stringify(Data)"

Comment: I have also try look like this. but not getting result. and i have also update my question you can see now.

Comment: Why is it that you are declaring data with a value of 0? Are you expecting to see data with a value of 0 after your $.get call?

Comment: I am just assigning value instead of null

Comment: I have also try look like:    $(document).ready(function () {
                var tt;
                var url = "/Controller/Action";
                $.get(url, null, function (Data) {
                    console.log(Data);
                    tt = JSON.stringify(Data);
                    $("#test").html(tt);
                    console.log(tt);
                });
            
                var data = $("#test").html();
                console.log(data); }); // getting empty string

Comment: Sorry, but I'm no longer sure what you are asking anymore

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75988/discussion-between-jatin-gadhiya-and-walker-boh).